# How to selected drowndown list options in web browser

Tags: c#

Im working a web browser automation project.
this is exampel code ;

```html
<select name="ctl00$ctl00$main$Content$cbReceiverCity" id="ctl00_ctl00_main_Content_cbReceiverCity" tabindex="40" class="custom-select" onchange="javascript:GetTowns(this);void(0);" style="width:170px;" size="5">
    <option selected="selected" value="-1">-- choose one --</option>
    <option value="1">Portugal</option>
    <option value="2">Spain</option>
    <option value="3">France</option>
    <option value="4">Germany</option>
    <option value="5">Italy</option>
</select>
```

and my c# code;

> HtmlElement enter =
>   webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_ctl00_main_Content_cbReceiverCity");
>                enter.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "5");
>                enter.InvokeMember("onchange");

but,Index value does not change. How can I change this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
enter.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "5");
```

with this

```
enter.Children[5].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

where 5 is the index of the option you want to select